# Rewindable XML Reader

Tags: c#, .net

I've already checked Google and come up relatively empty. Before I begin writing my own XML parser, I thought I'd ask here: I am looking for a low-resource, fast, rewindable (or backwards-only, non-cached) XML-Reader. Due to some data structures I am playing with, the forward-only XMLReader that ships with .NET would take an insane amount of time / resources to do the kind of parsing I want, and loading the entire document into memory using XMLDocument will eventually break the machine.

So, does anyone know a way to make XMLReader seeks backwards from element to element (without some insane overhead)? Or does anyone know of a backwards-seeking XML Reader? Or should I just write my own reader?

Thanks,
-R

Comment: How about reversing the XML files before processing them?

Comment: Is it possible to provide your XML and what you'd like to do with it? You question is pretty generic and now-a-days you have better choice than `XMLReader` that ships with .NET

Comment: How does the XML look and why do you need to seek backwards? How big is the file?

Comment: Do you want true backward or bottom of the document tree up?

Comment: The file size will probably breach the 40 GB barrier in the near future, so I am attempting to head off the problem before it becomes pressing issue.

Comment: Bottom of the document tree upwards. Something like starting with the last element, and working upwards.

Comment: I would try to find another way to hold my data instead looking for *fast, rewindable* XML reader. 40GB xml file is not normal.

Comment: 40GB is way too big to be messing with XML, it is a ridiculously inefficient storage format. That size of data generally needs to be in a database for efficient searching.

Comment: Well, it's actually Zipped XML. And though I played around with the idea of storing the nodes in the SQL Server database, I am having trouble thinking of database / table design(s) and the associated SQL queries that go with them that do not sound insane in my head. ^_^

Comment: Can you describe/post one complete instance of your data/XML?

Comment: @RonSavage : Post 40GB of XML?

Comment: Actually, I meant post one complete record of the data in the XML to define it's format - so we could suggest a table schema for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The file size will probably breach the 40 GB barrier in the near future

XML is not a good candidate for what your trying to do. A database would be much more efficient to handle such a large volume of data. You should load the data from the XML into a database, and then you can work on that database.

Comment: What are you saying different then @RonSavage who commented 2 hours ago?

Comment: @L.B, it's completely different... Ron Savage suggested using DataTables, which means having the data in memory. I'm suggesting to insert the values directly into the database as it is read from the XML.

Comment: `40GB is way too big to be messing with XML, it is a ridiculously inefficient storage format. That size of data generally needs to be in a database for efficient searching`

Comment: @L.B, it's what I said... I said that XML is inefficient for 40GB of data, and that instead it should be stored in a DB. Now, perhaps the OP is receiving the data as XML, in that case he needs to store it in a DB. I don't understand why you downvoted my answer which is completely in line with what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry You are correct but you gave the same answer as @RonSavage's comment But it seems he changed his mind in his answer. (My upvode is blocked until you edit your answer.)

Comment: Hmm. My worry is that using the database as a solution may result in a truly hideous number of joins, for relatively little gain. Since I am primarily doing linear reads, going with a database would not result in a speed up, and would be computationally expensive.

Comment: @user978122, well you would have to do some profiling to make sure, but I think it would be more efficient...

Comment: Hmm. There may be something to this. Another user dealing with a somewhat related issue has informed me of a possible way to cut down on the resource use.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try loading your XML file into a DataSet object with DataSet.ReadXML(). It works for many cleanly formatted XML files (less than 1GB in size). Then you can search for your data in the DataTables inside the DataSet, using the DataTable.Select syntax.

If you have an example XML file, you can try loading it with this toy app I made that loads XML into a DataSet and displays the DataTables in a grid for editing: http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/WTFXMLSetup_1_9_0.msi. That will show if your XML will fit cleanly in a DataSet.

Obviously as noted above in my comment, 40GB is way too large to deal with in XML using any tools - it should be in a database.

Source for the project is in: http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/wtfxml.zip

For everyone down-voting this, please note the timeline of events:

```
5 hours ago - asked (with no size criteria) and initially answered as above
4 hours ago - size criteria mentioned
4 hours ago - My comment: too big for XML, use a database
```

Comment: Doesn't that load the whole XML into memory?

Comment: It loads the data in the XML into memory but parses the XML out of it, so it's not the same size in memory as the XML text is.

Comment: Indeed, but in this case, I do not want to load anything into RAM that is not a part of the structure I am parsing.

Comment: -1  `40GB is way too big to be messing with XML, it is a ridiculously inefficient storage format. That size of data generally needs to be in a database for efficient searching`  I think this is the most correct answer

Comment: @RonSavage `You could always try loading your XML file into a DataSet object with DataSet.ReadXML()` Really? 40GB xml data? Funny :)

Comment: You guys should reeeally pay more attention to the timeline of comments, and to who actually pointed out that 40GB was too big for XML and should be in a database - that was me.